# How to cluster LDA/LSI topics generated by gensim?

Tags: python, k-means, natural-language, latent-semantic-analysis

I'm an enthusiastic single developer working on a small start-up idea. I reduced a corpus of mine to an LSA/LDA vector space using `gensim`. Now I have a bunch of topics hanging around and I am not sure how to cluster the corpus documents. I see that some people use k-means to cluster the topics. Can someone please elaborate?

---

So i had some to properly read up LDA/LSA and took a look at the gensim source. i did not realize that the Similarity Matrix was actually an MXM matrix where M is the number of documents in my corpus, i thought it was MXN where N is the number of topics. Using the matrix as an input to scikit's linkage function, i was able to create a heirachical cluster. Well, i was able to do it for a 1000 docs in my corpus (need more ram to handle a large corpus).

Comment: You can treat the topic mixture vector for each document as its position in this latent topic space. Simply run your clustering using this as the input data. What is the point of the hard clustering though?  The topic mixtures already give you a lot of information about how documents are similar/different.

Comment: Would you kindly provide more details on how you did it? That will be a great help. Best regards,

Comment: i actually have to take a look at the code again, the project is currently in hiatus. I will take a look later on today.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example.
You need copy **matutils.py** and **utils.py** from **gensim** first, and the directory
should like the pic blow.

[image]

The code blow should be in **doc_similar.py**.
Then just move your data_file into directory data and change **fname** in function main.

```
#coding:utf-8

from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
import cPickle
import logging
import utils
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matutils
from collections import defaultdict

data_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')
work_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model', os.path.basename(__file__).rstrip('.py'))
if not os.path.exists(work_dir):
    os.mkdir(work_dir)
os.chdir(work_dir)

logger = logging.getLogger('text_similar')
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

# convert to unicode
def to_unicode(text):
    if not isinstance(text, unicode):
        text = text.decode('utf-8')
    return text

class TextSimilar(utils.SaveLoad):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conf = {}

    def _preprocess(self):
        docs = [to_unicode(doc.strip()).split()[1:] for doc in file(self.fname)]
        cPickle.dump(docs, open(self.conf['fname_docs'], 'wb'))

        dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docs)
        dictionary.save(self.conf['fname_dict'])

        corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]
        corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(self.conf['fname_corpus'], corpus)

        return docs, dictionary, corpus

    def _generate_conf(self):
        fname = self.fname[self.fname.rfind('/') + 1:]
        self.conf['fname_docs']   = '%s.docs' % fname
        self.conf['fname_dict']   = '%s.dict' % fname
        self.conf['fname_corpus'] = '%s.mm' % fname

    def train(self, fname, is_pre=True, method='lsi', **params):
        self.fname = fname
        self.method = method
        self._generate_conf()
        if is_pre:
            self.docs, self.dictionary, corpus = self._preprocess()
        else:
            self.docs = cPickle.load(open(self.conf['fname_docs']))
            self.dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load(self.conf['fname_dict'])
            corpus = corpora.MmCorpus(self.conf['fname_corpus'])

        if params is None:
            params = {}

        logger.info("training TF-IDF model")
        self.tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus, id2word=self.dictionary)
        corpus_tfidf = self.tfidf[corpus]

        if method == 'lsi':
            logger.info("training LSI model")
            self.lsi = models.LsiModel(corpus_tfidf, id2word=self.dictionary, **params)
            self.similar_index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(self.lsi[corpus_tfidf])
            self.para = self.lsi[corpus_tfidf]
        elif method == 'lda_tfidf':
            logger.info("training LDA model")
            self.lda = models.LdaMulticore(corpus_tfidf, id2word=self.dictionary, workers=8, **params)
            self.similar_index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(self.lda[corpus_tfidf])
            self.para = self.lda[corpus_tfidf]
        elif method == 'lda':
            logger.info("training LDA model")
            self.lda = models.LdaMulticore(corpus, id2word=self.dictionary, workers=8, **params)
            self.similar_index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(self.lda[corpus])
            self.para = self.lda[corpus]
        elif method == 'logentropy':
            logger.info("training a log-entropy model")
            self.logent = models.LogEntropyModel(corpus, id2word=self.dictionary)
            self.similar_index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(self.logent[corpus])
            self.para = self.logent[corpus]
        else:
            msg = "unknown semantic method %s" % method
            logger.error(msg)
            raise NotImplementedError(msg)

    def doc2vec(self, doc):
        bow = self.dictionary.doc2bow(to_unicode(doc).split())
        if self.method == 'lsi':
            return self.lsi[self.tfidf[bow]]
        elif self.method == 'lda':
            return self.lda[bow]
        elif self.method == 'lda_tfidf':
            return self.lda[self.tfidf[bow]]
        elif self.method == 'logentropy':
            return self.logent[bow]

    def find_similar(self, doc, n=10):
        vec = self.doc2vec(doc)
        sims = self.similar_index[vec]
        sims = sorted(enumerate(sims), key=lambda item: -item[1])
        for elem in sims[:n]:
            idx, value = elem
            print ' '.join(self.docs[idx]), value

    def get_vectors(self):
        return self._get_vector(self.para)

    def _get_vector(self, corpus):

        def get_max_id():
            maxid = -1
            for document in corpus:
                maxid = max(maxid, max([-1] + [fieldid for fieldid, _ in document])) # [-1] to avoid exceptions from max(empty)
            return maxid

        num_features = 1 + get_max_id()
        index = np.empty(shape=(len(corpus), num_features), dtype=np.float32)
        for docno, vector in enumerate(corpus):
            if docno % 1000 == 0:
                print("PROGRESS: at document #%i/%i" % (docno, len(corpus)))

            if isinstance(vector, np.ndarray):
                pass
            elif scipy.sparse.issparse(vector):
                vector = vector.toarray().flatten()
            else:
                vector = matutils.unitvec(matutils.sparse2full(vector, num_features))
            index[docno] = vector        

        return index


def cluster(vectors, ts, k=30):
    from sklearn.cluster import k_means
    X = np.array(vectors)
    cluster_center, result, inertia = k_means(X.astype(np.float), n_clusters=k, init="k-means++")
    X_Y_dic = defaultdict(set)
    for i, pred_y in enumerate(result):
        X_Y_dic[pred_y].add(''.join(ts.docs[i]))

    print 'len(X_Y_dic): ', len(X_Y_dic)
    with open(data_dir + '/cluser.txt', 'w') as fo:
        for Y in X_Y_dic:
            fo.write(str(Y) + '\n')
            fo.write('{word}\n'.format(word='\n'.join(list(X_Y_dic[Y])[:100])))

def main(is_train=True):
    fname = data_dir + '/brand'

    num_topics = 100
    method = 'lda'

    ts = TextSimilar()
    if is_train:
        ts.train(fname, method=method ,num_topics=num_topics, is_pre=True, iterations=100)
        ts.save(method)
    else:   
        ts = TextSimilar().load(method)

    index = ts.get_vectors()
    cluster(index, ts, k=num_topics)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_train = True if len(sys.argv) > 1 else False
    main(is_train)
```